# Cant get records between two dates

Tags: java, mysql, swing, date, jdatechooser

My problem is that I can't fetch all records that are between two dates.

I have two `JDateChooser`s.  When I select two dates like '10-apr-2011' to '20-apr-2011' I want all the records between those dates to be displayed in my `JList`. But I can't get any results in the `JList`.

I am using mysql database.

```
  private void Display(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    try 
    { 

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con= 
           (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(
             "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","ubuntu123");   
        java.util.Date jd =  jDateChooser1.getDate();
        java.util.Date jd1 = jDateChooser2.getDate();

        // PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select date from invoice where date = ?);

        // PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT date FROM invoice WHERE date BETWEEN ' ' AND ' '");

        PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT date FROM invoice WHERE date >= '+jd + ' AND date <= '+jd1 + '");

        pstmt.execute();  

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.getResultSet();

        int i =0;
        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

        while(rs.next())
        {   

            String [] data;
            data = new String[100];
            data [i] = rs.getString("date");
            jList1.setModel(listModel);
            listModel.addElement(data [i]);
            i = i+1;

        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("2nd catch  " + e);
    }        
}
```

Can anyone tell me where my mistake is?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you get any values in resultset ?

Comment: no Resultset is also blank..i think my query stuck me

Comment: Please share the value of `jd` and `jd1`

Comment: @kapil - check my post and see if it works for you. You need to make the change in format, if needed.

Comment: jd and jd1 have dynamic value that is choosing run time by the viewer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a `PreparedStatement` you can try:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT date FROM invoice WHERE date >= ? AND date <= ?");
pstmt.setDate(1,new java.sql.Date(jd.getTime()));
pstmt.setDate(2,new java.sql.Date(jd1.getTime()));
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: no suitable method found for setDate(int,java.util.Date)
    method com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date,java.util.Calendar) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date) is not applicable
      (actual argument java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date by method invocation conversion)

This error occures

Comment: @kapil See my updated answer. The issue was that setDate needs a java.sql.Date

Comment: @dan.. now i want records instead of date in JList then what should be the changes?

Comment: @kapil Glad that it worked. But I'm not sure what do you mean by records instead of date. Maybe you should ask another question with the new details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to alter your query. Something like this:-

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String jdStr = sdf.format(jd);
String jd1Str = sdf.format(jd1);
PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT date FROM invoice WHERE date >= '" + jdStr + "' AND date <= '" + jd1Str + "'");
```

Previously, in your query, the 2 parameters, `jd` & `jd1` were not getting append. This change will now append it in the query. The problem was with the `jd & jd1` not correctly being appended in the query.

**Note:-** I've added a SDF so that you could format your date in format needed and append it to the query.

Comment: No in this way JList show all the records not the specific that is between two dates only..

Comment: Then make sure, your dates are proper! I don't see any other problem, why it should fetch everything!

Answer (score 2):

You need to take out `jList1.setModel(listModel);` out of the loop

```
while(rs.next())
    {   

        String [] data;
        data = new String[100];
        data [i] = rs.getString("date");
        //jList1.setModel(listModel);
        listModel.addElement(data [i]);
        i = i+1;

       }

jList1.setModel(listModel);
```

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned by R.J.'s answer and then mine remove the `setModel` statement from loop

Answer (score 2):

1. never to create an `GUI Objects` inside hard and long running `JDBC`, nor inside `try` - `catch` - `finally`, on exception those Object never will be created
2. `DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();` should be created an local variable, and then isn't required to recreate a new `XxxListModel` on runtime
3. have to remove all elements from `listModel`, otherwise new `Items` will be appended to the end of `JList`
4. definition for `String [] data;` and `data = new String[100];` and `data [i] = rs.getString("date");` inside `while(rs.next()) {` are quite useless, because database records are stored from this array in `XxxListModel`, and accessible for other usage for elsewhere
5. `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` should be closed in `finally block` (`try` - `catch` - `finally`), otheriwe these `Objects` stays (and increasing)  in `JVM` memory,

Answer (score 1):

are you sure dates in SQL and date from java.util.Date are in the same format?

Try using

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);
```

to check whenever they are same.

jd and jd1 by default would differ by SQL date [@see SQL Dates](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way of using `PreparedStatement`, which is already prepared to handle Dates, so you **should not covert them to String**. Your code should look like this:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = ...
pstmt.setDate(...)
```

Also your query String is **not really using the jd as a variable**, you misused ' and "